# Plotting a sparse matrix using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a sparse data matrix. My data looks like as follows:

```
x1=rbinom(5,1,0.5)
x2=rbinom(5,1,0.2)
x3=rbinom(5,1,0.2)
data_co=data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

  x1 x2 x3
1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0
3  1  0  0
4  0  1  0
5  0  0  0
```

I want to plot the above matrix as follows:

1. x axis should be named as the row number
2. y axis should be labeled as the column number.

I tried the image function in R and got an output like this:
[image]

But the axis labels are not in the format that I want. Is this something that I can do using R?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a sparse matrix. It's a data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Transfer the rownumber as an id. Reshape to to long using `pivot_longer()`. Then sketch the plot using `geom_tile()`. Set the axis according to your specifications and fill by values. If you want to see the numbers you can use `factor()`. Here the code using the data you shared:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
data_co %>% rowid_to_column('id') %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(id),y=name,fill=factor(value)))+
  geom_tile(color='black')+xlab('x')+ylab('col')+
  labs(fill='Var',color='Var')
```

Output:

[image]

If colors need to be changed, you can use `scale_fill_manual()` defining the desired colors:

```
#Code 2
data_co %>% rowid_to_column('id') %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(id),y=name,fill=factor(value)))+
  geom_tile(color='black')+xlab('x')+ylab('col')+
  labs(fill='Var',color='Var')+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('magenta','yellow'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I want. However, Is there any way to change this into a different color scheme ?

Comment: @student_R123 Yeah sure, let me add some colors so that you can adapt to ones you like!

Comment: @student_R123 I have added an update for you. I hope that helps you!